# Adding Arguments to local file URL with google chrome in command line

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

I'm having some troubles while trying to open a local file in google-chrome as it gives me a weird URL in google chrome but prints just fine in the console.

Here is the output I get in the console:

> file:///home/user/Questionnaire/initialFr.html?id=902

Here is the address I get in chrome:

> file:///home/user/Questionnaire/initialFr.html%3Fid=902

From what I've gathered so far it has to do with chrome escaping the "?" since they have to be interpreted server-side. Is there a way around it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Basically running an experiment. I need to open a local file in the browser with some parameters that are computed in a c++ program from which I'm calling the the system call to google chrome.

Comment: If you are calling local file, there is no "server-side" and everything is evaluated in browser. This is probably some chrome-feature showing potentially "dangerous" characters safely encoded, since I don't see this happening in Firefox. If the only problem is the way how it is visible in the url bar, I believe there is no problem ;)

Comment: There is actually a problem as I need to parse this URL in my local file which contains JavaScript and html. Unfortunately I have to use chrome because some of the JavaScript code that I use doesn't work on other browsers

Comment: If you get it "correctly" in (javascript) console there is nothing to do. Or it gets "translated" somewhere else on the way from C++ application? Can you be more specific about this?

Comment: Except that I don't get it correctly in javascript console. I get this weird '%3' instead of my "?"

Comment: That's normal URL encoding. Just read up on that and I'm sure you'll figure out what to do.

Comment: Problem is I haven't figured it out yet. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Jakuje the problem is that as a consequence my page does not get open by google chrome so that I can't even check what I get in the javascript console or run any of my javascript code

Comment: @megamorf would you have any more insights to share?

Comment: Can you try to pass the url encoded to chrome? Like this: `file:///home/user/Questionnaire/initialFr.html%3Fid=902`

Comment: I tried it doesn't work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to pass parameters to a client-side HTML page, when using local files, the hash `#` should be used instead of question marks `?`.

So, basically: `file:///home/user/Questionnaire/initialFr.html#id=902`

Comment: Interesting. Do you know how to link to a particular anchor in a page if the page is hosted locally, seeing as the # symbol is being used to replace the question mark?

Comment: @ultrafez I'm not quite sure (can't test it now), but I think using the `#` twice could work. I mean, for example, `initialFr.html#id=902#anchor`